# How to handle browser language notification in android using appium?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, browser-automation, android, appium

I was trying to automate a website which is in german. But when I run the test on android device using chrome browser, language translator notification appears. Can anyone let me know how to handle this notification using appium on android device?

Comment: It should be a browser/device popup with standard interactions.  You should be able to "accept or reject" it and then continue the test.

Comment: If that was so easy to accept or reject, I wouldnt have as ked the question here. I tries every possibility but that doesnt work.Do u have any other workaround?